# How do I split a string at a separator unless that separator is followed by a certain pattern?

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a Python string

```
string = aaa1bbb1ccc1ddd
```

and I want to split it like this

```
re.split('[split at all occurrences of "1", unless the 1 is followed by a c]', string)
```

so that the result is

```
['aaa', 'bbb1ccc', 'ddd']
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use a negative lookahead assertion: `1(?!c)` *(1 not followed by c)*

Comment: `re.split("1(?!c)", "aaa1bbb1ccc1ddd")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use negative-lookahead with regex and the `re` module:

```
>>> string = 'aaa1bbb1ccc1ddd'
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"1(?!c)", string)
['aaa', 'bbb1ccc', 'ddd']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def split_by_delim_except(s, delim, bar):
    escape = '\b'
    find = delim + bar
    return map(lambda s: s.replace(escape, find),
               s.replace(find, escape).split(delim))

split_by_delim_except('aaa1bbb1ccc1ddd', '1', 'c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not as pretty as regex, my following code returns the same result:

```
string = 'aaa1bbb1ccc1ddd'
```

## Split the string at all instances of '1'

```
p1 = string.split('1')
```

## Create a new empty list so we can append our desired items to

```
new_result = []

count = 0
for j in p1:

    if j.startswith('c'):

        # This removes the previous element from the list and stores it in a variable.
        prev_element = new_result.pop(count-1)

        prev_one_plus_j = prev_element + '1' + j

        new_result.append(prev_one_plus_j)

    else:
        new_result.append(j)

    count += 1

print (new_result)
```

## Output:

['aaa', 'bbb1ccc', 'ddd']

Comment: This traverses iterators twice (once to do `string.split('1')` and once to process `p1`) and has double the memory footprint. Regex is the far better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewCole, that makes a lot of sense. It really is useful to learn regex well!